# Where can I obtain Stack Overflow API datasets?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-dump

I need some Stack Overflow API datasets for some analysis that I wish to do.

Are there any Stack Overflow API  datasets that have been collected over the years? If yes, can someone let me know where I would find them?

Comment: I think you're looking for http://stackapps.com/ or http://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go for data dumps.

From the [about](https://data.stackexchange.com/about) page:

> The Stack Exchange trilogy data dumps are hosted at [ClearBits!](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/1117-may-10). You can subscribe via [RSS](http://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-overflow-data-dump.rss) and be notified every time a new dump is available.
> Have fun remixing and reusing; all we ask is for proper attribution.

You can access the data dumps for any of the Stack Exchange sites, but if you're only interested in Stack Overflow, click on the link, or go directly [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).